# Django how do i work with button in a template

Tags: django

I have a button in templates, when i click the button it will create a object. I am new to django. What would be the correct way to work with buttons.

```
   <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type=submit name="submit">
    </form>
```

views

```
           def create_object(request):
           if 'submit' in request.POST:
                                                                                                       Employee.object.create(emp_name='test',emp_email='test@gmail.com')
            HttpResponse(" ")
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Which object/instance will be created? Does it depend on some more POST data than just hitting a button? Has it to be saved into the db?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
def create_object(request):
    if 'submit' in request.POST:
    #Employee.object.create(emp_name='test',emp_email='test@gmail.com')<--- just commented out
button = "<button>your button</button>"
return render_to_response('your.html',{'button':button},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template

```
{{button|safe}} <------------ will show your rendered button
```

tell me if you have problems in understanding this code

Comment: It seems doesnt work for me and getting no error. when i click button i just get a blank page